# Does torrent seeding "access" files?

Tags: linux, bittorrent

Can I tell for sure using the time a file was "accessed" the last time (as reported by Nautilus), that I didn't seed it via torrent afterwards? Does seeding "access" files?
I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) and use qBittorrent.

Comment: Have you tried to check it yourself? It seems simple enough.

Comment: Yeah, probably you are right. Seems like seeding does not change it, but starting the seeding changes atime of the files.

Comment: Or not... Seemed like they were changed at the start of qbittorrent for some files, but now I tried restarting it and atime didn't change.

Comment: that's most likely implementation-specific. A client might access the files on startup, on scheduling the torrent or only when it actually has to upload any data from them.